# How can i build native android apps from any website (Not Website convert into apps)

Tags: android

Suppose , i have a website and its running well . Now i want to make an android apps using website information or My apps will contain all the information of that website already contain or how can i connect an android apps with any website.

Some solution :
1. convert website into android apps (i don't need this).
2. JSON API (i think this is best option for me ).
May be there has so many option but this time i can't remember. option is best for me if it is possible . but i don't how to create a JSON API from website .
but i don't know how to do it. please let me know share something for better understand.
or if has any other better solution for this problem please let me know .

Comment: Unlikely you will find any option to _convert_ your website into an app. Can users not just use a web browser?

Comment: You don't "create a JSON api" from a website... You make your website (and app) load information both from an API. But you never mention any type of data you're displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a web app, using android native web view or some technologies like ionic, etc..., or create a comprehensive API endpoint in your backend/website and start build an android app from scratch.
creating a web app is a simpler approach but has so many shortcomings in design, functioning and flexibility aspect, so if you want a competitive app with a fine extendibility feature the best option is native android development. but it could be more costly as it needs both backend and android development.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is already implemented and running, you can just create an Application using a https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView. Basically, this is an injected Browser, allowing the user to access your Website without actually open chrome/firefox etc. on the smartphone.

To improve the usability, the layout of your website should be able to dynamically resize the content.

If you wish to actually implement an application (Activities/Fragmets...) you need to connect to your backend server the same way your website is retrieving the information.

Comment: first option is the web conversion into android apps . i dont need this . 
How can i connect my apps with backend server . please give me some resources or courses link .